# Could a laptop be harmed being plugged into the same surge protector as a portable air conditioner?

Tags: surge-protection

Would a simple surge protector power board protect a laptop from surges with a portable air conditioner also plugged in that's turning on and off?

Comment: @harrymc Your description makes the laptop + air conditioner on a surge protector sound like a big no no. I do have my desktop PC plugged into an UPS, but I didn't think it would be a good idea to plug the laptop charger into a live socket on the UPS every time I needed it and I don't want to have to power down the PC and UPS just to connect the laptop charger. Could I perhaps leave the laptop charger permanently plugged into the UPS even when the laptop is not connected?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The air conditioner wouldn't cause power surges, but exactly the opposite. The surge protector is no protection here.
For real protection and you will need a UPS with battery for the computer.

If the air conditioner suddenly draws too much power, this could have the same effect as
sudden power off, with unknown results.
Most likely it will cause not much trouble and at most cause the computer to reboot,
but you might be unlucky.

A stable power source is always recommended for computers.

Comment: If the laptop has it's own battery, it should be even better than a UPS (I read they don't always instantly take over, especially with some low voltages), shouldn't the laptop keep running on battery if the charger quits, just without being charged? The laptop charger might be another matter... but input voltages of 100 - 240 V seem common